# Formatting a DateTime column in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date-formatting

I have a column that stores DateTime in a MySQL database. I want to compare the Date part (and not the time) to the current day. I am not sure what method to use as I am very new to PHP.

```
$today=date("Y-m-d");
$sql="SELECT journey_id FROM tbl_journeys WHERE identity='$driver_id' AND DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y %m %d')='$today'";
```

I tried this way but it's not working. In the statement, `date` is a column in the table which I need to trim to only Year-month-day

Comment: Why not use the MySQL function for today? `AND DATE(date) = TODAY()`

Comment: Flip the date part the other way. Format the $today variable, not the column.

Comment: `$today` contains `-` between the parts of the date, but `DATE_FORMAT()` puts spaces between them. How do you expect them to be equal?

Comment: @Barmar you are right...I added the dash and it ddnt work but I also realised my server's time is incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using different characters between the year, month, and day in the two formats.

```
$today=date("Y-m-d");
```

puts hyphens between them, while

```
DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y %m %d')
```

puts spaces between them.

Change one of them to match the other, e.g.

```
DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Or you could just do it all in MySQL:

```
$sql="SELECT journey_id FROM tbl_journeys 
      WHERE identity='$driver_id' AND DATE(`date`) = TODAY()";
```

Comment: After adding dashes and correctly configuring servers time it worked